# Properties of the pullback metric of $\mathbb{R}^3$ according to the stereographic projection.

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

I am self studying differential geometry and I got stuck on an exercise about metrics.

Let $F_{4}$ be an embedding of $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $S^2$ defined as follows
$$ F_{4}(u,v)=(\frac{2u}{u^2+v^2+1},\frac{2u}{u^2+v^2+1},\frac{u^2+v^2-1}{1+u^2+v^2}).$$
Call $g_4=(F_{4})^{*}(\bar{g})$ where $\bar{g}$ is the euclidean metric of $\mathbb{R}^3,$ is the metric $g_4$ bounded, is this metric complete, is it flat?
I have calculated the metric $g_{4}$
$$ g_{4}(u,v)=\frac{1}{(u^2+v^2+1)^2} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 \\
0 && 1\end{bmatrix}.$$
Clearly $g_4$ is not flat, but is it bounded? Is it complete? The embedding is not proper, so I would have to use another strategy to prove $g_4$ is complete. As for the boundness I could not find a way to estimate this integral along a curve $(u(t),v(t)),$
$$ \int_{a}^{b}\frac{\dot{u}^2+\dot{v}^2}{(u^2+v^2)^2} \, ds,$$ maybe it would be easier to restrict the class of curves considered? For example would it help to consider only the piecewise linear curves? Any ideas?

Comment: The first thing to do is to figure out the image of $F_4$. As for the integral you wrote, it is indeed easy to do if you use a simple curve.

Comment: @Deane sorry I should have called the map stereographic projection to clarify that I already know the image, it is the unitary sphere minus $(0,0,1)$

Comment: Is the sphere minus the north pols complete? Use the precise definition of completeness to answer this. As for whether it is flat, you could compute the Gauss curvature. Or use any other properties you know about flat surface in Euclidean 3-space.

Comment: @Deane I cannot answer in general because you must always refer to a metric when you speak about completeness. But I think a got the hint, I have to take a sequence of points which get nearer and nearer to the north pole to show that $(\mathbb{R}^2,g_{4})$ is not complete.

Comment: Have you learned how to define the distance between two points on a surface? You can use that distance function to turn $S^2$ into a metric space. You can then figure out a way to show that the north pole is a finite distance away from any point on the sphere. You should eble to see that the metriic $g$ written with respect to $(u,v)$ is bounded using your formula for it.

Comment: @Deane I get it now, for every couple of points it is enough to find a curve of finite length joining the two points.